# How to maintain a shell function definition inside a Makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

This is the script I intend to run in a Makefile:

```
default:
    myFunc() { echo "Called"; };
    myFunc;
```

When I call `make`, the function is not defined. So I made the following changes:

```
default:
    myFunc() { echo "Called"; }; myFunc;
```

Which allows the call to the function to work as intended.

However, I want to reuse the function definition in subsequent commands which will not be in the same line as the function definition.

Is there a way to extend the scope of a shell function definition to the whole rule?

Comment: When make is running a command it starts a new shell for that command; functions don't carry over. You can store the function definition in a make variable and expand it, or you can use line extensions to make your subsequent commands be run with the same shell despite not being on the same line, but you can't make a function defined by one shell be available in another shell that isn't a child process of the first.

Comment: (if you start `make` _from a shell script_ using an interpreter that supports exported functions, and you override the make variable `SHELL` to point to that same shell, you can also define the function in the parent process and let it be inherited in the children; but I'd call that an ugly hack: people who see a makefile expect to be able to call `make` directly, instead of needing to use a shell wrapper that does environment setup first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the below is written scoped to your question where the goal is to make a function declaration apply "to the whole rule", not to the entire makefile as a whole; folks attempting to do the latter may need to ask a separate question.

---

#### Using GNU make: The `.ONESHELL` feature

As [@MadScientist pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73015418/how-to-maintain-a-shell-function-definition-inside-a-makefile#comment128959421_73015465), GNU make (starting in version 3.82, released in 2010) also [offers a `.ONESHELL` feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html), which invokes a single shell with all the lines in a rule. Using this, the code might look like:

```
.ONESHELL:
default:
        myFunc() { echo "Called"; }
        myFunc
```

---

#### Portable Standard Practice: Line Continuations

By contrast, to be portable to non-GNU make implementations, one would use line continuations:

```
default:
        myFunc() { echo "Called"; }; \
        myFunc
```

Comment: If you have GNU make 3.82 or better, another option is to use the `.ONESHELL` feature.  However be aware that once turned on, this will be in effect for every recipe in the makefile and could have subtle effects.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html

Comment: @MadScientist, mind if I amend that into the answer, or are you working on your own?

Comment: I am not working on my own, feel free!